# Changing color of specific chartjs point

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible to change specific point color with dx chartjs?
I know how to change point colors for the whole series, but I can't find anything on changing specific points.

Comment: It's a good question. Also, I want to change a specific label color too. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
customizePoint
```

callback.

```
$("#container").dxChart({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    ...
    customizePoint: function() {
        if(this.value > highAverage) {
            return { color: '#ff4500', hoverStyle: { color: '#ff4500' } };
        } else if(this.value < lowAverage) {
            return { color: '#00ced1', hoverStyle: { color: '#00ced1' } };
        }
    },
    ....
}
```

});

You can find find [documentation](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Configuration?version=14_1#customizePoint) and [demo](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/VizGallery/#chart/chartsadvancedfeaturescustomizepoints)