# ChartJS - Different color per data point

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linechart, chart.js

Is there a way to set a different color to a datapoint in a Line Chart if its above a certain value?

I found this example for dxChart - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24928967/949195 - and now looking for something similar for ChartJS

Comment: There's a solution for the radius's size at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57070297/2457251 that might be useful for this case as well.

Comment: For recent versions of chart.js, you can achieve this by setting pointBackgroundColor to an array of colours (one per point), OR - more flexibly - by setting it to a function that sets the colour according to the context. For an example see my answer below (Nov 2019)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[For chartjs 2.0 see this following answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39295456/2598)

Original answer below.

---

Good question regarding ChartJS. I've been wanting to do a similar thing. i.e dynamically change the point colour to a different colour. Have you tried this below. I just tried it and it worked for me.

Try this:

```
myLineChart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor =   "rgba(000,111,111,55)" ;
```

Or Try this:

```
myLineChart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor =  "#FF0000";
```

Or even this:

```
myLineChart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor =  "lightgreen";
```

Then do this:

```
myLineChart.update();
```

I guess you could have something like;

```
if (myLineChart.datasets[0].points[4].value > 100) {
    myLineChart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor =  "lightgreen";
    myLineChart.update();
 }
```

Give it a try anyway.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm using this plugin in AngularJS application: http://carlcraig.github.io/tc-angular-chartjs/

But the code above, did let me get it done through setting up the usual way as per ChartJS documentation.

Comment: for me it is not showing points key itself, i don't know why? Need some help?

Answer (score 50):

In updating to version 2.2.2 of ChartJS, I found that the accepted answer no longer works. The datasets will take an array holding styling information for the properties.
In this case:

```
var pointBackgroundColors = [];
var myChart = new Chart($('#myChart').get(0).getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                data: dataPoints,
                pointBackgroundColor: pointBackgroundColors
            }
        ]
    }
});

for (i = 0; i < myChart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
    if (myChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] > 100) {
        pointBackgroundColors.push("#90cd8a");
    } else {
        pointBackgroundColors.push("#f58368");
    }
}

myChart.update();
```

I found this looking through the samples for ChartJS, specifically this one: ["Different Point Sizes Example"](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/different-point-sizes.html)

Comment: To control the point's border color, use the same approach, but with the `pointBorderColor` property.

Answer (score 38):

With recent versions of `chart.js` I would recommend doing this with [scriptable options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html).

Scriptable options give you an easy way to vary the style of a dataset property (e.g. line point colour) dynamically according to some function you provide. Your function is passed a 'context' object that tells it the index and value of the point *etc.* (see below).

Most chart properties can be scripted; the dataset properties for each chart type tell you the exact list (*e.g.* see [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) for line chart).

Here is how you might use scriptable options on a line chart (based on the [example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/options.html#scriptable-options) in the docs). On this chart negative data points are shown in red, and positive ones in alternating blue/green:

```
window.myChart = Chart.Line(ctx, {
    data: {
        labels: x_data,
        datasets: [
            {
                data: y_data,
                label: "Test Data",
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                fill: false,
                pointBackgroundColor: function(context) {
                    var index = context.dataIndex;
                    var value = context.dataset.data[index];
                    return value < 0 ? 'red' :  // draw negative values in red
                        index % 2 ? 'blue' :    // else, alternate values in blue and green
                            'green';
                }
            }
        ],
    }
});
```

The `context` object passed to your function can have the following properties. Some of these won't be present for certain types of entity, so test before use.

- *chart*: the associated chart
- *dataIndex*: index of the current data
- *dataset*: dataset at index datasetIndex
- *datasetIndex*: index of the
  current dataset
- *hover*: true if hovered

Comment: Thanks This works perfectly for me. But in case I want to draw the line with different color instead of the points in different color - as per the current value - where should I be making the changes?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for charts -> line -> dataset properties ...  you will see that you can style the line with backgroundColor and borderColor, which are also scriptable options

Comment: Belated apologies @jAntoni - doing the line in different colours is more complicated than I thought. It's still possible though: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778468/how-to-use-segment-property-to-color-line-border-color-based-on-value-in-chart

Answer (score 15):

Here's what worked for me (v 2.7.0), first I had to set pointBackgroundColor and pointBorderColor in the dataset to an array (you can fill this array with colours in the first place if you want):

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                data: dataPoints,
                pointBackgroundColor: [],
                pointBorderColor: [],
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Then you can monkey with the colours of the points directly:

```
  myChart.data.datasets[0].pointBackgroundColor[4] = "#cc00cc";
  myChart.data.datasets[0].pointBorderColor[4] = "#cc0000";
  myChart.update();
```

Some other properties to play with to distinguish a point: pointStrokeColor (it apparently exists but I can't seem to get it to work), pointRadius & pointHoverRadius (integers), pointStyle ('triangle', 'rect', 'rectRot', 'cross', 'crossRot', 'star', 'line', and 'dash'), though I can't seem to figure out the defaults for pointRadius and pointStyle.

Comment: `myChart.data.datasets[0].pointBorderColor[4] = "#cc0000";` its giving error (undefine) for me &  `myChart.data.datasets[0].pointBorderColor = "#cc0000";` change all points color & not particular points. is there anyone knows how to change particular points color ?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding what worked for me in the new 2.0 version.

Instead of:

```
myLineChart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor =  "lightgreen";
```

I had to use:

```
myChart.config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[4] = "lightgreen";
```

Not sure if that's because of a change in 2.0 or because I'm using a bar chart and not a line chart.

Answer (score 1):

For the new version in ChartJS, I found that you can specify every point information by adding a list of attributes with the data set, here is an example to make the last point with red color and the first 3 points with different point sizes:

```
datasets: [{ 
        data: JSON.parse("{{week_visits|escapejs}}"),
        label: "Visitors",
        borderColor: "#71b9ac",
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "#dab193",
        pointStyle: 'circle',
        pointRadius: [7,6,5,5,5,5,5],
        pointHoverRadius: [9,8,7,7,7,7,7],
        pointBackgroundColor: ['red','#dab193','#dab193','#dab193','#dab193','#dab193','#ffffff'],
    },
```

Look at the **pointRadius**, **pointHoverRadius**, and **pointBackgroundColor**, all have the same list size but every data with the same index '*7 for 9 for red, 6 for 8 for $dab193*' will be together as a point attribute.

**Note**: this code from Django templets, gets the data from views.py in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize the myChart in this manner,

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
```

you have to change line color by this code

```
  myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[0] ="#87CEFA";
```

---

If you initialize the myChart in this manner,

```
myBar = new Chart(ctx).Line(barChartData, {
```

you have to change line color by this code

```
myLineChart.datasets[0].points[4].fillColor =  "#FF0000";
```

Comment: 2.7.3 here, and there's no .points structure in the Chart object.

Answer (score 0):

most of the ways were too complex for me so here's how is solved it:
I am using react btw, so in the data parameter i was doing this

Before:

```
datasets:[
        {
            label: 'Maximum Predicted Temperature',
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.5,
            backgroundColor: ['red'],
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: max
        },
```

After:

```
datasets:[
        {
            label: 'Maximum Predicted Temperature',
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.5,
            backgroundColor: ['red','blue','green','yellow','orange','purple','pink','brown','grey','black','white','violet'],
            borderColor: ['red','blue','green','yellow','orange','purple','pink','brown','grey','black','white','violet'],
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: max
        }
```

the color will loop if your given data points are more than the number of colors provided and the color red will apply on every 12th data point it really helped me thought the solution is bit clumsy but gives more control hope this helps