# Chart.js line split color

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I currently have a dataset and I'd like to split the color of the line it produces at a certain point (before the point is green, after is red, for example). Is there any way to do this or would I have to render two separate lines onto the graph?

Comment: this might be helpful to you , please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159595/chartjs-different-color-per-data-point

Comment: that is related to the point color, whereas I am interested in changing the color of the line between the points

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible (in version 2.9.4). I checked the code in the GitHub repository to verify this:
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v2.9.4/src/elements/element.line.js

In the `draw` method the color to draw the lines is set only once, without a way to use different colors for different line segments.

The master branch (containing 3.0.0 beta code) also has no way to specify different colors for different line segments.