# Changing style of individual point Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to change the style of a single point in my Chart.js graph. I tried the solutions here

> [ChartJS - Different color per data point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159595/chartjs-different-color-per-data-point)

But none of them work for me. For example, to change the background color of the 4th point in my first dataset, I would try the following 2 solutions (and also removing/adding .config):

```
myChart.config.data.datasets[0].points[4].pointBackgroundColor = 'red';
myChart.config.data.datasets[0].pointBackgroundColor[4] = "red";
myChart.update();
```

to no effect. On the contrary, changing the style of the entire dataset works perfectly fine:

```
myChart.config.data.datasets[0].pointBackgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
myChart.update();
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/15766/; Why is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/15822/

You can use an array of colors to the `pointBackgroundColor` in the `options` as follows

```
pointBackgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
```

Then if you want to change any individual point color later you can do that as follows

```
myChart.config.data.datasets[0]['pointBackgroundColor'][4] = 'red';
```

I have attached the link to the updated jsfiddle. You can check that. Cheers!

Comment: Your array method works, but when working with ~100 points (all the same color before changing one individual point's color), do you know of a way to set the original array of colors without having it look like `['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', ...]`?

Comment: can you write a simple for loop to initialize the array elements to a single color?

Comment: Yeah, a tad ugly but it works fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah. According to chart.js documentation, for the `pointBackgroundColor` you can pass either a color or an array of colors. If you just pass a color, then you can't access it using indexes like we do with arrays. Glad I could help.

Comment: You can also use the .fill() function to initialize an array to a static value.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fill.asp